# Java. Jax-Ws wsimport. How can i update previously generated java.class?

Tags: java, jax-ws, wsimport

For my project i using wsimport from wsdl to generate java classes few month ago. I added in the classes some new code for my needs. Wsdl is now updated and i need to update classes in my project without overwriting my code, just update default code. How can i save my code after updating wsdl in my project?

Comment: Why can't you take a backup and use the old wsdl to generate classes again ?

Comment: this old wsdl has changed and i need import changes without overwriting my methods

Comment: You should always keep generated code apart from code you write yourself, for this very reason.

Comment: Y, i think so< its being my mistake.